# I have an image that is pushing the body away from the html element if the windows height shrinks

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, height

I'm building a website and the picture that is 256X480 on the home page breaks out of the body and pushes the body away from the html element, I'm a bit confused on how to handle this the image and its container dont seem to respond at all to the max-height property. Can someone explain why this is or point me to some resources that explain this and how to fix it, thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/9oy5n0he/

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 0, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 30%, rgba(0,150,255,.8) 100%), url("images/mainCover.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
/*nav and header*/
header{
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.8);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 8px solid black;
}
nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
}
header h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
header h1, nav a{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: arial;
}
header nav{
    display: none;
}

.main-nav{
    margin: 4px;
}
nav ul li{ 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

 nav a:visited, nav a,h1{
   color: white; 
}

.current-page{ 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

footer nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

footer nav ul{
    margin: 0;
}
footer nav li{
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.8);
}
/*home page*/
.bookWrapper{
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
}
 .bookLink {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.bookImage{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.amazonBookLabel{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.amazonBookLabel:after{
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: calc(50% - 17px);    
}
.amazonBookLabel:before{
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left:  40px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
}

/***responsive***/
@media screen and (min-width: 400px){
        header{
            height: 130px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
      header h1{
                font-size: 2em;
                align-self: flex-start;
                white-space: nowrap;
                border: 8px solid black;
            }
     header nav{
                display: block;
                align-self: flex-end;
            }
      .main-nav{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }
     .main-nav li{
                border-radius: 8px;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 1.3rem;
            }
    .characters:hover {
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
            }

     .drop-menu{
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            display: block;
            top: 33px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            left: -2px;
            background-color: rgba(255,165,0,.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.02);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
            z-index: 1;
            }
    .characters:hover .drop-menu{
             visibility: visible;
             opacity:1;
        }

    .drop-menu li{
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    } 

    footer nav{
                display: none;
            }
}
@media screen and (min-width:860px){
    header{
        height: 120px;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    header h1{
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    .main-nav li{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    header nav{
        margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    }
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 1109px){
    header h1{
        font-size: 3em;
        margin: 0 0 0 80px;
    }
    .main-nav > li{
        margin: 0 8px;
    }
    header nav{
        margin: 0 80px 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I put images in your code and am not seeing anything pushing body away from the html element https://jsfiddle.net/9oy5n0he/4/

Comment: yeah I guess it doesnt do it with smaller pictures, the one I have is 256x480 and its pushing the body away from the html

Comment: smaller pictures? Check the image I used, it's 2000x1333 http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg

Comment: oh sorry yeah youre right, I just noticed its doing the same thing  as the original image too its just not as easy to becasuse you have the size the window in a bit of an abnormal way, if you  keep the width of the window the full size of the screen and make the height about half the screen, the image starts to push the html away.

Comment: ah, gotcha. just a sec, I'll see if I can fix-a-roo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `height: 100%` on `html` is limiting the height and technically the image is overflowing html/body, so you won't see the background in that overflow.

A better technique is to remove the `height` on `html` (not necessary) and use `min-height: 100vh` on `body`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 30%, rgba(0, 150, 255, .8) 100%), url("images/mainCover.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/*nav and header*/

header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

header h1,
nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: arial;
}

header nav {
  display: none;
}

.main-nav {
  margin: 4px;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 4px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:visited,
nav a,
h1 {
  color: white;
}

.current-page {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

footer nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}

footer nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}

footer nav li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
}


/*home page*/

.bookWrapper {
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}

.bookLink {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.bookImage {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.amazonBookLabel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.amazonBookLabel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 17px);
}

.amazonBookLabel:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -45px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
}


/***responsive***/

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  header {
    height: 130px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    align-self: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 8px solid black;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  .characters:hover {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  }
  .drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    top: 33px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: -2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .characters:hover .drop-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .drop-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  footer nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:860px) {
  header {
    height: 120px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  header nav {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1109px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 0 0 80px;
  }
  .main-nav > li {
    margin: 0 8px;
  }
  header nav {
    margin: 0 80px 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Seraph Chronicles</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="main-nav-item current-page"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="main-nav-item characters">
          <a href="characters.html">Characters</a>
          <ul class="drop-menu">
            <li><a href="ethanClarke.html">Ethan Clarke</a></li>
            <li><a href="serenaKiriaga.html">Serena Kiriaga</a></li>
            <li><a href="MarcusFlynn.html">Marcus Flynn</a></li>
            <li><a href="EmilyAshdown.html">Emily Ashdown</a></li>
            <li><a href="MilesWest.html">Director Miles West</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="auther.html">Author</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <p class="amazonBookLabel">Get the first and newest addition of the trilogy here!</p>
    <div class="bookWrapper">
      <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Seraph-Chronicles-Kyle-James-Feller/dp/1520404999/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1496613120&sr=8-3&keywords=seraph+chronicles" class="bookLink">
        <img class="bookImage" src="images/bookCover.jpg" alt="image of seraph chronicles: evangelion for purchase">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="characters.html">Characters</a></li>
        <li><a href="auther.html">Author</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</main>
```